# Binary symmetric sources and information theory

Tags: information-theory

How can we generate 3 or more binary Sources using BSC channel.
As we know, BSC can be easily used to generate 2 binary sources with some cross-over-probability(say *p*). Eg, length of codeword(say *n*) `n = 1000; p = 0.2`, then input and output binary codeword will be having Hamming distance of approx 200. In this way we generate 2 Binary sources with 200 Hamming distance from each other.

My question is: How can we generate multiple Binary with same cross-over-probability or multiple binary sources with approx similar Hamming distance from each other. E.g: X, Y , Z, W. and they should have similar Hamming distance from each other(all combinations(X-Y)(X-Z) and so on).

And, there should be some way to calculate the joint entropy for them.
I am trying to make some scheme to do that, if u have some ideas .. just discuss it.
please let me know for any questions.. I will surely clear them

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you start by starting with a simpler special case?  What about the case $n=1$, and three sources?  Can you find one-bit random variables $X,Y,Z$ such that $\Pr[X \ne Y]$, $\Pr[Y \ne Z]$, and $\Pr[X \ne  Z]$ are all about 0.2?

Answer (score 1):

You want to generate $n$-bit random variables $X_1,\dots,X_m$ such that the Hamming  distance between $X_i,X_j$ is about $pn$.  Let me start by showing you how to do this for the special case where $n=1$; then I'll generalize.

Set $q = (1 - \sqrt{1-2p})/2$.  Pick a set $S \subseteq \{0,1\}^m$ of $m$-bit values, such that every element $s \in S$ has Hamming weight $qk$.  Now pick a random $s$ from $S$, randomly permute the bit positions of $s$, and assign this to $X_1,\dots,X_m$ (i.e., $X_i$  is the $i$th bit  of $s$).  I claim this will have your desired property.  Why?  Well,

$$\Pr[X_i \ne X_j] = \Pr[X_i=0,X_j=1] + \Pr[X_i=1,X_j=0] = 2q(1-q) = p,$$

so the expected value of the Hamming distance between $X_i,X_j$ will be about $p$, as desired.  The joint  entropy is easy to calculate: it is simply $\log_2 |S|$.

What if we want $n>1$?  Then we can just sample the first bit of $X_1,\dots,X_m$ as above; then sample the second bit of $X_1,\dots,X_m$ in the same way (iid; i.e., pick another  $s$ from $S$, and randomly permute its bit-positions); and so on.  This gives us a source where the expected value of the Hamming distance between any  two $X_i,X_j$ is about $pn$, and where the joint entropy is $n \log_2 |S|$.